# Divide matrix on both sides of an equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Here is the question I have to solve:

> Find value of $x$ if,
> $$
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & x & 1 
> \end{bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 3 & 2 \\
> 2 & 5 & 1 \\
> 15 & 3 & 2\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 \\
> 2\\
> x\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> =0
> $$

**My attempt:**
I divided on both side of the equation by $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 \\
2 & 5 & 1 \\
15 & 3 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}$ to get:
$$\frac{
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 \\
2 & 5 & 1 \\
15 & 3 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2\\
x\\
\end{bmatrix}}{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 \\
2 & 5 & 1 \\
15 & 3 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}} = \frac{0}{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 \\
2 & 5 & 1 \\
15 & 3 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}}$$
Which gives:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & 1 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2\\
x\\
\end{bmatrix} = 0$$
Solving this:
\begin{align} 
(1)(1)+(2)(x)+(1)(x) &= 0 \\
1 + 2x + x &= 0 \\
3x &= -1 \\
x &= \frac{-1}{3} \\
\end{align}
... which is the incorrect answer. **Is dividing both sides of the equation by the same value invalid in this case or how else is this approach wrong?**

Comment: What if you multiply out the matrices and see what equation that gives you on the LHS?

Comment: Matrix operation does not work this way. You will have to evaluate the expression on LHS and solve for $x$, like @Moo suggested.

Comment: @Moo Yes, by doing that I get the right answer, but I want to know why this is incorrect.

Comment: @Aditya, you cannot divide by matrices.

Comment: @sudeep5221, Is there a reason why matrix operations don't work that way? Sorry if I'm missing anything important

Comment: @Aditya, well, matrices aren't numbers. Their algebra is fundamentally different from the algebra of numbers. You cannot divide by a matrix just like you cannot divide by a set.

Comment: @aqualubix I think I understand, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to dividing by a matrix is multiplying from the left by its inverse.
It is true that...

$$ M^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
M
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2\\
x\\
\end{bmatrix} = M^{-1}0=0$$
But it is not valid to change the order of multiplication and conclude that...

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
M^{-1} M
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2\\
x\\
\end{bmatrix}=0$$

as you seem to have done

Comment: What you're showing as equality confuses me. There is no sense in the left side. There is a discrepancy in the sizes.

Comment: I think what I was trying to get across was...
$$ M^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
M
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2\\
x\\
\end{bmatrix}
\ne \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
M^{-1} M
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2\\
x\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: It's still unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish. When you say *which is not true in general*, you implicitly assume such a possibility, but here the left side is fundamentally wrong. I like to hear your feedback :).

Comment: I've edited my answer, I think it makes more sense now. The whole thing about "not true in general" was me thinking that the OP would be getting the correct answer if the matrix $M$ was the identity matrix, that thought sent me down a bit of a rabbit-hole.

Answer (score 3):

In linear algebra terminology, the expression you've having is known as quadratic forms. let $\boldsymbol{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n, A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, the quadratic form is expressed as
$$
\boldsymbol{v}^TA\boldsymbol{v}.
$$

In your case, the expression would look like this $\boldsymbol{v}^TA\boldsymbol{u}$ where $\boldsymbol{u}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. As a result, your case only requires expanding the expression and equating it to zero as has been addressed in the comments by @Moo. Using Matlab, I get

$$
x^2 + 16x + 28 = 0 \implies x_{1,2} = -14,-2. 
$$

Matlab script

```
syms x real
v=[1;x;1];
k=[1;2;x];
A=[1 3 2;2 5 1;15 3 2];
expand(v'*A*k)
```